# How to execute code to run as soon as a button is pressed?

Tags: android

When a button is pressed in Android you can use an setOnClickListener to execute code AFTER the user lift up their finger. How can you execute the code as soon as they press down?

Comment: create a class that extends `View` and override `onTouchEvent` then check for the `MotionEvent` `ACTION_DOWN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `setOnTouchListener` method:

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
           //do what you wish to
     return false;
    }
   }))
```

Comment: onTouch() will call repeatedly until user lift the finger up.

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //do something funny
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public class DownTouchButton extends Button implements OnTouchListener {

    private DownTouchButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private DownTouchButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private DownTouchButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("YourApp", "A down event");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your xml:

```
<com.your.package.DownTouchButton
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Down Press Me!"
/>
```